# What is the use of $g$-factor for magnetic moment of electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, terminology, history, magnetic-moment

$g$-factor is also called the spectroscopic splitting factor according to "Introduction to Solid State Physics" by Charles Kittel. So it can be presumed that it is related to the splitting of levels in spectroscopy measurements on atoms and acts as a correction factor for the magnitude of splitting of levels in a magnetic field given by

$$\Delta E = \vec{\mu_{B}} \cdot \vec{B},$$

with the correct expression given by

$$\Delta E = g \vec{\mu_{B}} \cdot \vec{B}.$$

My question is in regard to the relationship of g-factor to the events like the anomalous Zeeman effect, redressal of this effect using Stern Gerlach experiment, later postulation of spin.

Comment: This question is about the history of physics and belongs on the [hsm.se] site.

Comment: @baalkihaal. A very interesting question and not to be deleted from PSE I've taken the liberty to change the question a bit. Since you are know the chronology from the mentioned above events, let get an answer first for the use of this factor. If it does not meet your intention, you or me could reverse it back to the original question.

Comment: @G.Smith I agree with you. I did not know that there is a sub stack for history of science. If you can help me migrate the question, I will be grateful

Comment: @HolgerFiedler thank you for the observation. However most of the condensed matter textbooks elaborate on the use of the g-factor in accounting for the discrepancy between theoretical expression and experimental observation of the magnetic moment. My question pertains to when it was introduced (I am guessing it might be after the observation of anamolous Zeeman effect), who introduced (another guess might be some experimental physicist) it and why it was named so (my guess is it is related to the word "gyromagnetic"). So I will add your observation to the description of the question.

Comment: @baalkikhaal It seems that the question has to be redirected to [History of science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). but it’s still interesting, to see an answer to the actual (version of the) question.